# for loop in python exercise

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm looking for help to solve the below problem: Having 2 variables `beat` and `measures` I need to create a loop that prints, on the same line, all the beats times the number of measures. Nevertheless, every time it starts a new `measure`, the first `beat` should be equal to the number of the current `measure`.

Example: `beats_per_measure = 4`, `measures = 4` should give

```
1 2 3 4 2 2 3 4 3 2 3 4 4 2 3 4
```

and **not**

```
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

```
beat = beats_per_measure + 1
measure = measures + 1
for i in range(1,measure):
   for j in range(1, beat):
      print(j, end = " ")
```

This is the code I've tried to print beats x measure, but I'm not sure how to change that first beat to reflect the current measure.

Comment: In your print statement, you can replace `j` with `j if j>1 else i`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range (1, measure+1):
  for j in range(1, beat+1):
    if j==1:
      print(i, end="")
    else:
      print(j, end="")
```

Comment: A short elegant version mentioned earlier 
```
print(i if j ==1 else i, end="")
```

Comment: thanks but doesn't seem to work. it generates the following:
123451234512345123451234512345 instead of
1234223432344234

Answer (score 0):

Don't overthink a problem like this; adding an extra `print` provides the expected output, no `if` required:

```py
measures = 4
beats = 4

for measure in range(1, measures+1):
    print(measure, end="")

    # Start beat from 2
    for beat in range(2, beats+1):
        print(beat, end="")
```

Answer (score -1):

This code gave:123123123, maybe you lost "space" somewhere.

```
for i in range(1,4):
   for j in range(1, 4):
     print(j, end = "")
```

Comment: Hi КЕМ, welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your answer! This answer, unfortunately, does not answer the posted question, as the described problem is that the first beat of each measure should match the measure, while your proposed solution does not answer that.

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(1, 4):
        print(j, end = "")
```

Comment: This gives the exact output mentioned in the question as ***not*** wanted...

Comment: And apart from that it's just the exact same code as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75352065/6045800) and the question itself......